# Entity manager does not read newest state from database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, ejb

I am using EJB Container Managed Bean database handling.I am not able to begin transaction and end transaction.EJB handles this.Persistence provider is hibernate.

When I want to execute an sql query , it does not return to newest state from database.
I want to get entities whose status is WAITING, but although some entities is not in WAITING state, they are   retrieved execution of query.I think hibernate does not go to database for newst state.

I tried Query.setHint(String,Object), em.clear and some other things,But I am not able to.
O am dealing with this problem for one week.I tried anything.

Comment: If these db records get modified by some source outside the Hibernate-controlled application I would try disabling the second-level cache.

Comment: what kind of applications can modify db records? How can I disable second level cache?

Comment: Other enterprise applications, web frontends running on other server instances, other web apps, batch operations on the db, desktop applications, etc.  I'd suggest you disable second level cache, look what happens and then trace back to the culprit.  It's easy to do and if it works you'd at least have a starting point for further actions.

Comment: IMO, it is difficult to answer your question in the current form. You should provide some snippets where you are updating/fetching entities. Otherwise, there are numerous reasons why you don't see the updated entities. For example: fetching them before you have committed your transaction will still give you the old state.

Comment: But I can see the newest stete in database.So transaction is committed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new bean, added my method that retrieves entities whose status is Waiting as business method of that bean.I added @TransactionAtrribute(REQUIRES_NEW) annotation to declaration of method, this solved my problem